# jQuery - Fade in objects selected by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select several elements at once and fade them in on window load. The obvious

```
$('.home').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
```

didn't work, and neither did

```
$('.home').each(function(){
    $(this).delay(200).fadeIn(400); 
});​
```

What's the best way to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/FaqBX/4/

Comment: In what way "didn't it work"?

Comment: It's not a great idea to use DOM ready methods both from the jsFiddle sidebar as well as in your code. Choose one or the other. You have a conflict between `window.load` and jsFiddle's `onload` option. Your handler is assigned too late,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `$(window).ready` instead of `$(window).load` instead of document.load. And they need to be hidden first: http://jsfiddle.net/f3XhW/

Comment: `window` doesn't have a `.ready` event, but it does have a `load` event. If you do `$(window).ready`, it'll work as if you did `$(document).ready`

Comment: @aquinas I think he can use window load just fine, it wasn't working probably due to jsfiddle's setting, if you look at the left panel it already says onLoad. Probably using it twice caused problems.

Comment: @JakeRow123 is right. His `$(window).load` didn't work because the handler was assigned after the `window` had already loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You need to hide them before they can be faded in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.home').fadeIn(400);
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution is to first hide the elements, and then use the fadeIn:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.home').attr('style', 'display: none;');//to hide them
    // First attempt
    $('.home').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
    // Second attempt
    $('.home').each(function(){
        $(this).delay(200).fadeIn(400); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remember to have display:none on your .home

```
 $(window).ready(function() {
     $('.home').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

On jsFiddle you don't need `window.load` since it's the default.

```
$('.home').fadeTo(0, 0).delay(1000).fadeTo(400, 1);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/FaqBX/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FaqBX/7/

You need to hide the elements first (as user1689607), then I changed your fiddle to no wrap (head), since it was already window.load.

Answer (score 0):

Hide them before fading in and use document ready instead of window.load.

```
$(function() {
    // First attempt
    $('.home').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7LzQ/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/FaqBX/13/

Hide first in CSS:

```
.home { display: none; }
```

If you must use a delay:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.home').fadeIn(400);
}, 200);
```

Otherwise:

```
 $('.home').fadeIn(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it with CSS before showing it.  You can't fade it in if it's already visible.

HTML:

```
<div class="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
<div class="home">
    <p>This is the home.</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.home').fadeIn(400);
});​
```

CSS: `.home {display:none;}`​